# PHP - How to add two arrays with a string in between

Tags: php, arrays, json, variables

I have two arrays. I want to add `:` in between them and add them both into another array.

```
$temp = json_decode($csv[$indexLoc['allowance_json']], TRUE);

$details = is_array($temp)?(array_key_exists('details', $temp)?$temp['details']:''):'';
$anytime = is_array($temp)?(array_key_exists('anytime', $temp)?$temp['anytime']:''):'';

$deals[$counter]['deal_mins'] = $details .":". $anytime;
```

I need that code above to work.
I have also the basic one that always works

```
$deals[$counter]['deal_mins'] = is_array($temp)?(array_key_exists('details', $temp)?$temp['details']:''):'';
```

That one works, but I need to have two arrays separated by `:` instead.

Comment: Errors?  What exactly doesn't work? Looks OK.

Comment: Arrays can not be separated by `:`.

Comment: Can you try to create a [mcve]? There's some code here, which is nice, but we really need to see at least an example of input, an example of the output you're trying to get, and an example of what you're getting instead.

Comment: Does he maybe want to create a new JSON object from the values?

Comment: Okay so, let me explain it again with a different way.

Comment: I'm having a "json_decode" and Im just trying to save 2 fields into the database with a ":" between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting any errors? Your code looks fine.

```
$allowance_json = '{"details":"foo", "anytime":"bar"}';

$temp = json_decode($allowance_json, TRUE);

if (is_null($temp)) throw new Exception(json_last_error());

$details = (isset($temp['details']) ? $temp['details'] : '');
$anytime = (isset($temp['anytime']) ? $temp['anytime'] : '');              

echo $details . ':' . $anytime;
```

That output is a string. The string values you pulled out of there concatenated by a `:`. With the line of code below you are pushing that string back into an array. Is that what you want?

```
$deals[$counter]['deal_mins'] = $details . ":" . $anytime;
```

Comment: It just gave me "Array:' in the db.

Comment: Well I don't know what you are doing between here and the database. If you `var_dump($deals[$counter]['deal_mins'])` you won't get anything about an *array*. You'll get a string of text. Assuming that in your example  `$details` and `$anytime` are strings. You should check that. I can't say as you've never shown the contents of `$csv[$indexLoc['allowance_json']]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, because of you I understood everything and was able to fix the problem.